# What are the ?\(, ?\[, ?\{ symbols in emacs lisp?

Tags: characters

I've came across [this](https://github.com/timcharper/evil-surround/issues/86#issuecomment-258552759) comment in an [evil-surround](https://github.com/timcharper/evil-surround) issue, which stated this code:

```
;; use non-spaced pairs when surrounding with an opening brace
(evil-add-to-alist
 'evil-surround-pairs-alist
 ?\( '("(" . ")")
 ?\[ '("[" . "]")
 ?\{ '("{" . "}")
 ?\) '("( " . " )")
 ?\] '("[ " . " ]")
 ?\} '("{ " . " }"))
```

And it actually works. but what are those strange `?\` symbols? What are they doing? What do they mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs represents
[characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Char-Syntax.html#Basic-Char-Syntax)
with the `?a` syntax (or `?\X` for special characters, where `X` is one of them).

```
(characterp "a")                        ; => nil
(characterp ?a)                         ; => t
```

They evaluate to integers:

```
(integerp ?a)                           ; => t
```

They are *not* single-character strings, so the following will throw an error:

```
(string-equal "a" ?a)                   ; => (throws an error)
```

You can [convert](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/String-Conversion.html) them to [strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Strings.html#Creating-Strings) using:

```
(char-to-string ?a)                     ; => "a", note: semi-obsolete
```

or just a plain old:

```
(string ?a)                             ; => "a"
```

So now you have:

```
(string-equal "a" (string ?a))          ; => t
```

And for your special characters like parentheses and braces:

```
(list (string-equal "(" (string ?\())
      (string-equal "[" (string ?\[))
      (string-equal "{" (string ?\{)))  ; => (t t t)
```

Comment: Dan, could the evil-surround author have chosen to implement the `evil-surround-pairs-alist` variable with string (e.g. `"("`) leads instead of integer (e.g. `?\(`) leads? Why didn't he just use the string format?

Comment: @ninrod: in principle, yes: keys in an alist can be strings.  But characters will be a faster lookup because you can test for equality with `eq` (so `(eq ?a ?a)` evaluates to `t`), whereas string equality is slower to evaluate.  In effect, an alist with character keys can use `assq`, but one with string keys needs the slower `assoc`.  Whether or not you'd ever *notice* the speed difference depends on a) the list length, and b) how often you run the function.  It's also likely that he's querying the *characters* around point with `char-before` and `char-after`, and wants to skip conversion.

Comment: (minor) `?\  ` can be used for any character, not just special characters. So you *can* (but you need not) use `?\g` instead of `?g`.

Comment: @Drew: almost, but not quite, I think.  For example, `?a` is the [character representation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Char-Syntax.html#Basic-Char-Syntax) of lowercase "a" while `?\a` is the character representation of `C-g`, and `?t` represents lowercase "t" and `?\t` represents the `tab` character.  So both `(eq ?a ?\a)` and `(eq ?t ?\t)` evaluate to `nil`.  However, it does work for some other characters: `(eq ?z ?\z)` evaluates to `t`.

Comment: @Dan: Ah yes, right you are. It is true for characters for which there is not some other escape sequence defined. That is, as long as it is not one of the se: `\a`, `\b`, `\t`, `\n`, `\v`, `\r`, `\e`, `\s`, `\\   `, and `\d`. The relevant manual page is (elisp)[*Basic Char Syntax*](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Char-Syntax.html).